# Build a double from a stream of chars

Tags: c#, stream, floating-point

Back in my [calculator post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/87918/cc-c-calculator/87942#87942), janos suggested I either find a better way to read a `double` from a `StreamReader` or else go the whole way and build a `double` from scratch.  I looked through a few `stream`s, but the only one I found that supported reading a `double` was the [`BinaryReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  This, unfortunately, reads exactly 8 bytes, and the data is stored as a `char` (or rather, as an `int` representation of a `char`), so I could enter the equation "5+5", and it would crash when it read the "+".  If you know of a better solution, I would prefer using it.

```
private double GetNextNumber(StreamReader dataStream)
{
    double value = 0;
    int decimalLevel = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        if (!"0123456789.".Contains((char)dataStream.Peek()))
        {
            break;
        }
        char token = (char)dataStream.Read();

        if (token == '.')
        {
            if (decimalLevel == 0)
            {
                ++decimalLevel;
                continue;
            }
            throw new InvalidDataException("Invalid number format.");
        }

        int digit = int.Parse(token.ToString());

        value = value * 10 + digit;

        if (decimalLevel != 0)
        {
            ++decimalLevel;
        }
    }

    return value / Math.Pow(10, decimalLevel - 1);  // use "- 1" because value increments just before ending loop
}
```

Please analyze my code as thoroughly as the compiler does.

Comment: Even though this has a bug, it's not worth closing. You thought it was working code, and you asked for comments based on it.

Comment: Still, you shouldn't edit the existing code. I'm reverting it as per http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c/1765#1765

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should avoid `while (true) { … }` loops wherever it is possible to do so.  Here, it's very obviously avoidable!

```
while ("0123456789.".Contains((char)dataStream.Peek()))
{
    …
}
```

This parser leaves much to be desired in terms of handling

- negative numbers (or you should document the fact that they are unsupported)
- `e` notation for powers of ten
- overflow and small numbers, due to excessive multiplying and dividing by powers of ten

Personally, I would avoid the entire headache by appending all plausible-looking characters to a `StringBuilder`, then calling `double.Parse(string)`.

Comment: I had a guy once tell me on SO that `while (true) { if (condition) { break; } ... }` was a preference of style. I just didn't even respond. Gave up and left.

Answer (score 5):

You're multiplying the integer part of the number by 10^{decimalLevel-1} and then dividing it again. That seems to be needlessly introducing round-off error. How about splitting the code into "before decimal point" and "after decimal point" and factoring out common parts into a new method? Also that would make it easier to handle scientific notation, which your code currently doesn't.

Also, I have a problem with

> ```
> int digit = int.Parse(token.ToString());
> ```

It would be better to use an array or hashtable, rather than making a new temporary `string` in order to call `int.Parse` on it.

Answer (score 3):

I think your original code that used `double.TryParse` is fine. In some languages (like C), there are methods that try to find a number at the *start* of the given string. This is annoying when the whole string you have should be a number, but it could be useful here.

Unfortunately for you, there is no such method in C#, hence my conclusion that your original code was okay.

Answer (score 1):

This line has a bug when returning a value with no decimal value, as pointed out by mjolka:

```
return value / Math.Pow(10, decimalLevel - 1);
```

It evaluates to `value / 10 ^ -1`, which essentially returns `value * 10`.

This can be fixed in either of two ways:

```
return value / Math.Pow(10, decimalLevel == 0 ? decimalLevel : decimalLevel - 1);
```

Or, replace this section:

```
        value = value * 10 + digit;

        if (decimalLevel != 0)
        {
            ++decimalLevel;
        }
    }

    return value / Math.Pow(10, decimalLevel - 1);  // use "- 1" because value increments just before ending loop
}
```

With this:

```
    if (decimalLevel == 0)
    {
        value = value * 10 + digit;
    }
    else
    {
        value += digit / Math.Pow(10, decimalLevel);
        ++decimalLevel;
    }
}

return value;
```

The first method is slightly faster according to my profiler.